# NFC communication: What happends when an NFC enabled phone comes in contact with a tag?

Tags: android, nfc

I have been reading information on NFC but could not find exact process or sequence of steps that happens when an NFC mobile phone comes in contact with an NFC tag?

In more detail i got to know how the antenna, coil etc generate the magnetic field and how data is transferred, but i want to know 
whether any handshaking happens in the first stage?
Or What data is transferred between 2 NFC enabled phones before the actual sharing of a photo or any information happens.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you not [see](http://www.antenna-theory.com/definitions/nfc-antenna.php) the external links in the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_field_communication)?

Comment: This does not look like a programming question. Perhaps http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ is a more suitable place to discuss this topic.

Answer (score 1):

For explanation purposes, lets say the actual hardware communication of magnetic field generation, etc. etc. is the hardware layer of communication.

On the android OS layer, there is something called NfcManager ( a service ) that runs in the background when you enable "Nfc" settings. This service is responsible for converting the raw byte data that is received from the below layers, which could be the kernel or the hardware layer, depending on how you look at it.

Once the service picks it  up, [this link should give you a basic idea](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#dispatching) as to how it is pushed into the application!

As far as 2 NFC phones go, this is not an extremely informed opinion, but im guessing from sheer experience. In the case of a data that needs to be sent below a certain quantity, there is no "pairing" that happens. It identifies the other 2nd NFC device and simply sends out data. In the case of photos or anything larger, i would assume it pairs it using Bluetooth and sends out the data.